# Hyper-V not capturing windows key anymore

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

This morning, Hyper-V suddenly stopped capturing my Windows key altogether. I'm running a Linux VM and use the windows key extensively as a hotkey. This worked perfectly until this morning. Yesterday, `Win+B` would open the browser in my VM, like it should. Now it brings up the taskbar in the host VM.

The Keyboard setting is set to "Use on the virtual machine"

Answer (score 0):

Un-/Re-installing Hyper-V fixed it. No idea what caused it.